# C# и задание параметров в config - файле

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, config

Доброго времени суток!

Есть библиотека классов, в которой есть класс, имеющий некоторые приватные поля:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private char someSymbol;
    private double someDouble;
}
```

Необходимо с помощью конфигурационного файла инициализировать данные поля значениями (к примеру, `someSymbol = 'x'`, `someDouble = 0.0001`), чтобы при использовании данного класса эти значения уже лежали в данных полях.
Как правильно написать конфигурационный файл и как правильно считать с него значения? И, как я понимаю. для этих целей лучше использовать стандартный App.config файл.

**UPD.** Это должны быть неизменяемые параметры приложения, которые можно устанавливать снаружи.

Comment: Что лучше использовать для этого, зависит от вашей конкретной задачи. Расскажите, какую (более общую) проблему вы решаете.

Comment: @VladD я пишу immutable-класс `Polynomial`, реализующий логику работы с полиномами. Там необходимо задать с помощью config-файла значение поля `double epsilon`, которое сравнивается с коэффициентами полинома, и если коэффициент меньше данного значения, то коэффициент обнуляется. Это необходимо сделать для того, чтобы не нужно было пересобирать библиотеку при изменении значения `epsilon`

Comment: @VladD так я ведь описал общую проблему:) _Как правильно написать конфигурационный файл и как правильно считать с него значения?_

Comment: Ага, то есть это неизменяемый параметр приложения, который можно устанавливать снаружи. Хорошо, понял. (Мне кажется, стоит добавить эту информацию в вопрос.)

Comment: А не лучше ли этот параметр сделать параметром библиотеки, и не заставлять пользователя библиотеки класть значение в app.config?

Comment: @VladD Не слышал про такой метод. Может быть, это и лучше:) Просто нам на курсах по .NET предложили способ с config-файлом (но я ушел раньше и не смог послушать как это сделать), поэтому и спрашиваю про данный способ:)

Comment: @VladD Если Вас не затруднит, можете описать оба способа?:) Или хотя бы покидать ссылок с примерами, а то на msdn без примеров, и сложно разобраться из-за этого.

Comment: Окей, сейчас попробую. Я с телефона, так что будет медленно.

Comment: Да и чем плохо, когда пользователь задает параметры в config-файле? Ведь сейчас это повсеместно используется (в том же PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с `app.config` проще всего реализовать, как написано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892083/276994):

У вас в `app.config` должен появиться код наподобие такого:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="epsilon" value="0.0001" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Для чтения используйте такой код:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;

string epsilonString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["epsilon"];
double epsilon = double.Parse(epsilonString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Вам понадобится добавить ссылку на сборку `System.Configuration`,  если ещё не добавили.

Точно так же добавляется символьное или строковое значение (вам понадобится ещё одна секция `add`).

Имея два значения, лучше всего скормить из объекту через его конструктор:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private char someSymbol;
    private double epsilon;

    public SomeClass(char someSymbol, double epsilon)
    {
        this.someSymbol = someSymbol;
        this.epsilon = epsilon;
    }
}
```

---

Однако же, если речь идёт о конфигурации библиотеки, я бы сделал это по-другому: создал бы в библиотеке класс, описывающий конфигурацию, и использовал бы его. Например, часто можно обойтись статической конфигурацией:

```
public static LibraryConfiguration
{
    static public double Precision { get; set; } = 0.1;
    // тут другие конфигурационные свойства
}
```

Таким образом, приложение, использующее библиотеку, сможет отконфигурировать её:

```
LibraryNamespace.LibraryConfiguration.Precision = 0.0001;
```

где-нибудь в начале программы.